# Why can't Dictionary<T1, List<T2>> be cast to Dictionary<T1, IEnumerable<T2>>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections, casting

I'm wondering why I can't just cast (I have a vague idea this might have something to do with that co/contravariance stuff?), and am I forced to copy the elements of the first dictionary to a new one in order to get the type I want?

Comment: paste your code example.. you are probably not using Dictionary<> properly..

Comment: This has been answered many times as it's a very frequent question.  The short answer is because a reference to Dictionary<T1, IEnumerable<T2>> would allow you to add an T2[] array, which would be incorrect since the type is Dictionary<T1, List<T2>>

Comment: @James Michael Hare I see. Sorry for the duplicate; I'm sure someone will close it.

Comment: This is rather trivial operation with the `ToDictionary` extension method. However, the result is a *new* Dictionary: `var d2 = d1.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value.AsEnumerable())` or so.

Comment: @JCooper: No worries, I haven't found the duplicate yet - it may have been a subtle variation - but I tried to sum it up below, though not in the great detail Eric Lippert always provides in his answers...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot do this because they aren't the same type.  Consider:

```
        var x = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

        // won't compile, but assume it could...
        Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<int>> xPrime = x;

        // uh oh, would allow us to legally add array of int!
        xPrime["Hi"] = new int[13];
```

Does this make sense?  Because `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` says the `TValue` is `List<int>` which means you can `Add()` a `List<int>` as a value.  If you *could* cast this to a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<int>>` it would mean the value type is `IEnumerable<int>` which would mean you could `Add()` **any** `IEnumerable<int>` (`int[]`, `HashSet<int>`, etc) which would violate the original type.

So, a `List<T>` can be converted to a `IEnumerable<T>` reference because `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, but that does not mean that `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>` implements/extends `Dictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>>`.

Put more simply:

```
Dictionary<int, Dog>
```

Can't convert to

```
Dictionary<int, Animal>
```

Because the latter would allow you to add Cat, Squirrel, etc.

Comment: Makes sense; I'll make a copy then (I won't actually be modifying the resulting collection, but the type system doesn't know that).

Comment: JCooper: Cool, as pst mentioned above, you can use LINQ to do that for you, like: `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<int>> xPrime = x.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value.AsEnumerable());`

Answer (score 1):

You can not cast, because it still is a `Dictionary<T1, List<T2>>`

Lets say

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> d1 = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<int>> d2 = (Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<int>>)d1; // this is the invalid cast
d2["one"] = new int[0]; // valid for d2
List<int> list1 = d1["one"]; // would fail
```

Answer (score -1):

yes, it's an issue with covariance. I believe this was corrected with .net 4.0

Comment: JasonMeckley: Not quite, you can convert a List<T> to an IEnumerable<T> but you can't convert a Dictionary<T, List<T2>> to Dictionary<T, IEnumerable<T2>>

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare, thanks for clarifying. my assumption was wrong.

Comment: No worries.  It took me a while to fully see the subtlety.