# C# IDictionary with ICollection values without exposing implementation details

Tags: c#, generics, collections, covariance

I'm setting up a Dictionary with values of some sort of collection type as follows:

```
IDictionary<string, ICollection<decimal>> goodPrices = 
    new Dictionary<string, List<decimal>>();
```

However, this line of code results in an compilation error about not being able to implicitly convert the right-hand side to the left-hand side.  Obviously, the following line produces no error:

```
IDictionary<string, List<decimal>> goodPrices = 
    new Dictionary<string, List<decimal>>();
```

So what is the correct way of declaring "goodPrices" as a set of string-collection pairs without exposing the underlying implementation of the collection?

Comment: You can always do `new Dictionary<string, ICollection<decimal>>()` and then just assign `List`s to dictionary keys, e.g. `goodPrices["test"] = new List<decimal> { 3.30m };`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this :

```
IDictionary<string, ICollection<decimal>> goodPrices = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<decimal>>();
goodPrices.Add("myString", new List<decimal>() { /* my values */ });
```

Comment: Ah, of course!  Both your answer and @Patryk's are the way to go.   I belatedly found the following SO post on the underlying reason why the implicit conversion fails: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734272/why-cant-dictionaryt1-listt2-be-cast-to-dictionaryt1-ienumerablet2)